# Standardize date format using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

From `1-20-2017` (a string), I want to format a date as `yyyy-mm-dd` , like `2017-01-20`.

I've tried to dig into the [Moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/), but couldn't find any method that does this. I don't want an ISO date, I just want it to remain as string.

Comment: Just for fun: `let [m, d, y] = '1-20-2017'.split('-'); console.log([y, m, d].join('-'));`

Comment: Neither of those methods will pad numbers < 10, though.

Comment: @BenM, fare enough! If it's needed Moment is more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) in combination with `moment()`:

```js
var newFormat = moment("1-20-2017", "M-DD-YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = newFormat;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: why not m-d-yyyy?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to moment object then format it out in desired format.

```
moment('1-20-2017', 'M-DD-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```